# Autostart all LightDM seats and show one as default

Tags: lightdm, multiseat

I configured a media-center server running Debian with LightDM, Leapcast and Plex. What I want to accomplish is the following. There should be three LightDM seats, one default seat on which I can login; one seat that runs Leapcast (Chromecast emulator); and one seat that runs Plex Media Center. The last seat should show up as default.

Below you can find the relevant part of my lightdm.conf:

```
[Seat:0]
vt=7

[Seat:1]
allow-guests=false
autologin-user=media-center
autologin-timeout=0
greeter-hide-users=true
session-setup-script=start-chromecast
vt=8

[Seat:2]
allow-guests=false
autologin-user=media-center
autologin-timeout=0
greeter-hide-users=true
session-setup-script=start-media-center
vt=9
```

This configuration file enables the three seats, as intended. The problem I am facing now is that the default seat (the seat that is shown after booting) seems to be random, sometimes `tty7` show up at boot time (showing the login screen) and sometimes `tty8` shows up (which auto-logins and runs Leapcast). Another problem is that when `tty7` shows up as default, `tty8` is not started automatically.

So what I want is

1. to be able to choose the default virtual terminal and
2. make virtual terminal 8 and 9 (Leapcast and Plex) start automatically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For question #1: LightDM doesn't have that functionality builtin, but you can hack it. In /etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf, add a `greeter-setup-script`. The script can then use `sleep` (to wait for things to settle) and `chvt` to switch to whatever virtual terminal you like. (In your case, you'd want `chvt 7`).

For question #2: I think if you have it switch to tty8 and tty9 before switching to tty7, lightdm will start all three. (You might need a `sleep` in between the switching to let lightdm get started.)