# Display manager on multiple tty

Tags: fedora, display-manager, lightdm

I recently upgraded from Fedora 23 to 25, which seems to have broken my display manager configuration.

I was using lightdm and was able to switch between 3 GUIs running *lightdm* by just hitting `ctrl+alt+Fn`, n being the number of the tty. This started lightdm automatically on each tty I had configured.

After the upgrade, lightdm was completely broken. I managed to get it running again by modifying the configuration and changing, I think it was `[DefaultSeats]` to `[Seat:*]`. Now it is running, but only on the tty that has exactly the `minimum-vt` number. So if I set `minimum-vt=7,` for example it will only run on tty7; the others don't autostart anymore.
On tty8-12, I just get a blinking underscore and lightdm doesn't react to the switching according to the logs when running `lightdm -d`. tty1-6 are normal console ttys.

Output of `lightdm --show-config` (which composes all configurations and shows the one that is ultimately used to start lightdm):

```
[LightDM]
 minimum-vt=7
 user-authority-in-system-dir=true
 seats=seat0, seat1, seat2
 minimum-display-number=0

[Seat:*]
 session-wrapper=/etc/X11/xinit/Xsession
 xserver-command=X -background none
 greeter-session=lightdm-gtk-greeter

[Seat:seat0]
vt=7

[Seat:seat1]
vt=8

[Seat:seat2]
vt=8
```

Unfortunately I couldn't find any documentation on the `vt=` option but it was working on Fedora 23. I read something about a `use-vt=` option [here](https://wiki.kubuntu.org/LightDM/Specs/BasicMultiseat). But it seems to be something planned and not yet implemented. [Here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/87169/autostart-all-lightdm-seats-and-show-one-as-default) is another post that about the vt option. I tried this configuration, but maybe I'm missing something.

Apparently lightdm is ignoring both the `vt=` and `use-vt=` options. `lightdm -d` said that it loaded the configuration for `seat0` and it didn't matter to which value I set it, the actual vt remained the `minimum-vt=` value.

I also tried adding `-sharevts` to the standard `xserver-command` which left me stuck in the vt that lightdm took me to first. So it may be working like that but I can't switch vt. This may be because of the hard-coded `-no-vtswitch` option that is automatically passed to the X server, but I'm not sure as I found many configurations in older forum posts that even manually passed that option to X and it was working for them.

I'd like to be able to autostart and switch between the GUIs again. I'm also ok with another display manager. I already tried ssdm, but there doesn't seem to be an option for multiple seats at all.

Comment: Perhaps not really helpful, but just a side note : do not skip releases when upgrading.

Comment: @shaiba Thanks for the tip, I'll keep that in mind. Although I didn't encounter any issues apart from that yet.

Comment: @Anthon may I consult you as you participated in a [post](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/87169/autostart-all-lightdm-seats-and-show-one-as-default) related to this issue? Thank you!